# Sidekiq logging Redis queries

Tags: logging, redis, sidekiq

I am trying to debug sidekiq at low level.

In order to do this I want all queries to be logged.
Redis client logger can be enabled with:

```
redis.client.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
redis.set('a', 'b')
```

Results in:

```
D, [2014-05-13T11:35:34.787624 #46689] DEBUG -- : Redis >> SET a b
D, [2014-05-13T11:35:34.788274 #46689] DEBUG -- : Redis >> 0.27ms
```

It seems to be working for all libraries using redis-rb. But not for sidekiq because there is no direct access to `Redis::Client` object.

How such logging can be enabled for sidekiq?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, try `redis-cli monitor`

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of sidekiq-redislog which is what i use in the Sidekiq admin console for exactly this reason: https://github.com/rpocklin/sidekiq-redislog